# What is the difference between these two methods of finding the Key with associated highest Value?

Tags: c#, linq

I am reviewing some code written by someone and am having difficulty understanding why they went about finding the maximum value's key in this way. Can someone explain it and let me know which one is any "better" aka, quicker? (if any)

FYI, this is being used in a modal value calculation.

**Original** method (I don't exactly understand the second foreach loop):

```
// Begin Calculating the Modal Value
Dictionary<double, double> counts = new Dictionary<double, double>();

foreach (double cond_value in condDataToDouble)
{
    if (counts.ContainsKey(cond_value))
    {
        counts[cond_value] = counts[cond_value] + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        counts[cond_value] = 1;
    }
}

sourceMode = double.MinValue;
double maxVal = double.MinValue;

// Get the Max (modal) Value:
foreach (double key in counts.Keys)
{
    if (counts[key] > maxVal)
    {
        maxVal = counts[key];
        sourceMode = key;
    }
}
```

**My method:**

```
// Begin Calculating the Modal Value
Dictionary<double, double> counts = new Dictionary<double, double>();

foreach (double cond_value in condDataToDouble)
{
    if (counts.ContainsKey(cond_value))
    {
        counts[cond_value] = counts[cond_value] + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        counts[cond_value] = 1;
    }
}

// Get the Max (modal) Value:
sourceMode = counts.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).First().Key;
```

My main concern is that I just don't understand what they are doing and I want to learn. I understand my way which at-least is more concise in terms of code length. I know that doesn't necessarily make it any "better" though. Can someone help explain this?

Comment: Your code will fail if there is no entries in the dictionary - it will throw an exception when you do the .First()

Also, you are not using maxVal in your second piece of code - is this intentional? You're only getting sourceMode, which is the key in your dictionary.

Comment: Eser, thanks! As to the first comment, I guess this would solve that? var modalValue = counts.Count() > 0 ? counts.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).First().Key : 0;`

Comment: Regarding your proposed new solution: first, why is zero the right answer when there are no elements in the dictionary?  How would you tell whether a zero is the "right" answer vs the "default" answer?  Second, suppose I give you a jar with any number of pennies in it, and ask you if there is at least one penny.  Do you have to count the pennies in the jar to answer that question?

Comment: John, from curiosity, what is the type of **condDataToDouble** (i.e. list, array or just enumerable of doubles)?

Comment: Hi Ivan, it is a double array. I accidentally omitted this from the original post. `double[] condDataToDouble = new double[NumberOfDataPoints];` where `NumberOfDataPoints` is some integer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am reviewing some code written by someone and am having difficulty understanding why they went about finding the maximum value's key in this way.

You might consider asking that person.

> Can someone explain it and let me know which one is any "better" aka, quicker? (If any)

Why is "quicker" the same as better?  First off, we don't even know that either piece of code is *correct*. Second, there are many metrics for betterness other than speed.

Third, if you want to know which of two things is faster, **run them both with a stopwatch going** and then you'll know.

Fourth, which is faster is irrelevant; the relevant question is *are either of them too slow*?

> Can someone help explain this?

My advice would be to run through the code you don't understand in a debugger; that will help you understand how it works.

Another bit of good advice is to think about how you would solve the problem outside of a computer domain.  Here, I have a million cards each with a number on them, of any size. I'm going to take a thousand of those cards, shuffle them, and ask you to find the largest. How would you solve that problem?  Would you solve it by completely sorting the thousand cards and then taking the highest?  Or is there a faster way to do it? If you can find a faster way to find the largest number on a thousand cards other than sorting them, you can understand how the first algorithm works.

Comment: I would just go through them and pick out the largest number, I wouldn't bother sorting, that's an extra step. I see what they did now, I guess I just didn't understand the reason for the "sourceMode = double.MinValue;" part, but I also get that now. They are just getting the absolute lowest value that a double can represent. That way it does not interfere with the "max Value" Whose to say that the data won't have negative values?  (actually I know that can't happen, but that is a "just in case" scenario, so I get it now. )

Comment: @JohnAugust: A common variant to reduce the confusion you encountered is to use a variable named `currentHighest` and initialize it to the first element of the dictionary (rather than to some arbitrary unreachable minimum).